# ive been getting stuck on getting this table to work can someone help me?

Tags: java

I am a noob programmer, and have been getting stuck a lot lately.

On this example i have the basics of the table, but dont know how to proceed.

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    double row;
    double add = 0.25;
    int y = 15;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        row = 10 + add;
        g.drawString( i + "        " + row, 10, y +=15);
    }
}
```

I know its just gonna be a small add to the code, but i really dont know what.

I have tried alot of things like using multiple for statements but that didnt work as well.

This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

This is what i want it to look like:

[image: This is what i want it to look like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line, in for loop makes problem `row = 10 + add;`.
In each loop iteration row will have value `10 + 0.25 = 10.25`.

Perhaps, this is how your method should look.

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    double row = 10;        
    double add = 0.25;
    int y = 15;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        row = row + add;
        g.drawString( i + "        " + row, 10, y +=15);
    }
}
```